# Hover not working in FF

Tags: html, css, dom, hover

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #B9D3EE;
}

ul li a:link,
ul li a:visited,
ul li a:active {
  width: 100%;
  color: blue;
}

ul li a: hover {
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #B9D3EE;
}
```

In IE the above code will highlight the complete cell when hovered.
But in FF it will only highlight the link that is within it.
**I would like FF to highlight the complete cell as IE does.**

Here is the list:
Keep in mind that only the first link has been created because I have just started creating this list and stopped to test it when I noticed this problem.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">beauty</a></li>
  <li>creative</li>
  <li>Info Tech. (IT)</li>
  <li>cycle</li>
  <li>event</li>
  <li>financial</li>
  <li>legal</li>
  <li>lessons</li>
  <li>medical</li>
  <li>marine</li>
  <li>pet</li>
  <li>automotive</li>
  <li>farm+garden</li>
  <li>household</li>
  <li>labor/move</li>
  <li>MKT/COMM</li>
  <li>office</li>
  <li>skill'd trade</li>
  <li>real estate</li>
  <li>health/wellness</li>
  <li>travel/vac</li>
  <li>write/ed/tr8</li>
</ul>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do not put a space between `a:` and `hover` (or anything else). It should just be `a:hover`. You will run into all kinds of problems in CSS without proper whitespace. (*Most notably, `div.cls1.cls2` is vastly different from `div.cls1 .cls2` or `div .cls1 .cls2`.*)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi now remove `with 100%` in your `anchor link` css and define `display block` in you **css** in `anchor`

as like this

```
ul li a: link,
ul li a: visited,
ul li a: active {

display:block; // add this line
width:100%; // remove this line

  color: blue
}

ul li a:hover{
width:100%; //remove this line
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #B9D3EE;
}
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/VkcG47oC)***

Comment: @SperanskyDanil i m not copypast please compare your answer in my asnwer

Comment: @SperanskyDanil now you edited answer ok now i thing you saw my anser and updated your answer . I thing you copy my answer ........

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `a` elements as block elements, so they will get all width of parents elements (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WasWE/).

```
ul li a:link, ul li a:visited, ul li a:active {
  display: block;
  color: blue;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #B9D3EE;
  color: #ffffff;
}​
```

Or you can add `hover` event to `li` elements (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XmwTV/):

```
ul li:hover {
  background-color: #B9D3EE;
}

ul li a:link, ul li a:visited, ul li a:active {
  color: blue;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all! The block display was the key. As far as the spaces between the a: hover etc. It isn't like that in my original code. That formatting somehow chnaged when I posted it here. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think that the hover pseudo-class would work on IE6, so, for better backward support, use the first approach?